# CCXT Exchange as local var in function and as attribute in class

Tags: python, attributes, init, ccxt

I have a question about Python and CCXT library.

If I write in a simple Func:

```
poloniex.apiKey = ""
poloniex.secret = ""
poloniex.fetch_deposit_address(currency_code)
```

It Works and call the API perfectly.

BUT If I create poloniex = ccxt.poloniex() as attribute like:

```
def __init__()...
self.__poloniex = ccxt.poloniex()
```

And next I use self.__poloniex in other func, It doesn't work.

Have you some ideas?
It Could be a Python or a CCXT library problem?

Thank you

Comment: I see you capitalized `Init` in `__Init__` it should be a lower case to be called when initializing the object, is that possibly the issue?

Comment: Great question... I don't understand why the object created and used in a function works.
But If I use the object created as attribute of the class, doesn't work...

The init func is created like: def __init__

Comment: And of cause it is `__init__()` and not `__init()__`.

Comment: No, I already use: def __init__()